# extract values from xml string using dataframe column values in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Below is a code snippet where i try to extract xml data values dynamically based on the dataframe column values.

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr,col,explode,udf
from pyspark.sql.functions import StringType

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("example").getOrCreate()

data = [("John","age", """<person><age RPH="1">25</age> <age RPH="2">250</age><prof>test1</prof> </person>"""),
        ("Alice","age", """<person><age RPH="1">30</age> <age RPH="2">250</age><prof>test2</prof> </person>"""),
        ("Bob","age", """<person><age RPH="1">28</age> <age RPH="2">250</age><prof>test</prof></person>""")]

columns = ["name","colm", "xml_data"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

def extract_value(xml_column, tag_name,rpval):
    print(xml_column, tag_name,rpval)
    xpath_expr = "xpath({}, '/person/{}[@RPH={}]/text()')".format(xml_column, tag_name,rpval)
    print(xpath_expr)
    return expr(xpath_expr)

test_udf=udf(extract_value,StringType())

def extract_value_age(xml_column, tag_name):
    xpath_expr = "xpath_string({}, '/person/{}')".format(xml_column, tag_name)
    return expr(xpath_expr)

df=df.select("*",expr("xpath(xml_data,'/person/age/@RPH') as rphval")).withColumn("rphvalue",explode("rphval"))
df.printSchema()
df = df.withColumn("age", test_udf(col("xml_data"), col("colm"),col("rphvalue"))).withColumn("old_age", extract_value_age("xml_data", "age"))
df.show()
```

here, for each `rph` value, i need to evaluate the `xpath` expression.
But i am getting error like below

```
24/01/23 12:57:17 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 2.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 3)
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Pythonfiles\xmlTest2024.py", line -1, in extract_value
  File "D:\spark\spark-3.2.3-bin-hadoop3.2\spark-3.2.3-bin-hadoop3.2\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\functions.py", line 1430, in expr
    return Column(sc._jvm.functions.expr(str))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm'
```

the print statements are correctly printing values but

1st print: `<person><age RPH="1">25</age> <age RPH="2">250</age><prof>test1</prof> </person> age 1`

2nd Print: `xpath(<person><age RPH="1">25</age> <age RPH="2">250</age><prof>test1</prof> </person>, '/person/age[@RPH=1]/text()')`

I am expecting each row for `rph` value as in the code

Comment: I am not using databricks, i am working on aws emr , pyspark environment

Comment: thanks Nicholas, but i have 1 more query. the other code works.
df = df.withColumn("old_age", extract_value_age("xml_data", "age"))
df.show()

here we havent declared extract_value_age as a udf
also if we pass parameter to this function it doesnt work,(only the above calls work and we cant pass dataframe column it doesnt work)

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `expr()` within the UDF is the issue in your code. `expr()` is designed to parse SQL-esque expressions and doesn't support usage of UDFs directly. Trying to use `expr()` function within your UDF `extract_value` to parse an XPath expression is causing the error.

https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-sql-expr-expression-function/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).